# How to safely escape a variable string (user input) in bash?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, string, escape-characters

I have a very simple chat-like tool that runs within a GNU `screen` session. The `screen` window is split, the top part is running `tail -f file.txt` and the bottom part is running a script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
while : ; do
        read -p "Message: " msg
        ctime=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
        echo "[${ctime}] User: ${msg}" >> file.txt
done
```

Very simple, but gets the job done with the requirements I have. There's only one problem: When I press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> or any of the arrow keys, it inserts an escape-sequence, like `^[[D` for example. And this messes up the file, resulting in terrible output.

So my question is simple: How can I escape the input from `read` so it's safe to write to the file?

I've tried `echo "[${ctime}] User: ${msg}" | strings >> file.txt` which made it a lot better, there were no big mess-ups anymore (e.g. nothing was overwritten or wrongly put out), but things are still not perfect (e.g. entering `te^[[Dst` would turn into `te\n[Dst` (the `\n` being an actual new line)).

Comment: @guillermochamorro Go ahead and post it, maybe me or someone else can find a way to improve on it! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a slightly different approach? Rather than remove the escape characters and sequences, you can allow users to use them to edit the input line with `read -e`.

If you want, you can take this even further by recording chat message history, like this:

```
...
read -e -p "Message: " msg
history -s "$msg"
...
```

With this, if someone makes a typo in a message, they can hit up-arrow, use left- and right-arrow to edit and fix the typo, then hit return to send the corrected message.

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic! I had no idea `-e` is a thing. This even allows ctrl+arrow-key to skip words and keys like ESC or F-keys simply don't write anything now. One question about the history thing: How exactly does that work? I've never heard about this other than related to the .bash_history | I'm marking this as the accepted answer, even though it doesn't exactly filter escape sequences like asked, this is a way more elegant and compact solution.

Comment: @confetti It's the same mechanism as bash's regular command history, but it won't be loaded from or saved in .bash_history unless you do this explicitly with `history -r` and `history -w` respectively. If you do want to save the entry history between chat sessions, you could put them at the beginning and end of the script (but I'd recommend changing the `HISTFILE` variable to something other than ~/.bash_history, so the chat history doesn't get mixed with your command history).

Comment: That is amazing, thanks for teaching me something new and great.

Answer (score 2):

Strip any non-printing character from the message string:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while read -p 'Message: ' message; do
        printf '[%s] User: %s\n' "$( date +%T )"  "${message//[^[:print:]]/}"
done >>file.txt
```

The parameter substitution `${message//[^[:print:]]/}` would expand to the value of the variable `message` with any non-printable character removed.  In the POSIX locale, the printable characters are the alphanumerical characters, the punctuation characters, and space (`[[:alnum:][:punct:] ]`, basically).

Comment: Thank you, this works. Also thanks for the `%T` hint! This still prints the `[D` part of arrow keys, I guess there's no way around this? It doesn't matter much, your answer at least doesn't insert the newlines and for me that is good enough this way.

Comment: @confetti You could possibly delete the extra characters somehow, but doing so reliably would probably require knowing more about what the escape codes special keys generate than what I do.

Comment: My assumption is that it may be just plain `[D` as text. Since this is within a `screen` session, things are a bit more weird than they should be, but it's fine like this so no worries! :)

Comment: @confetti Note that the function keys generates strings like `OQ` or `[20~`, and it could so it would be difficult to remove fixed strings. But as you said, at least you now only get printable characters in the output.